# Arguments for naturalistic moral realism

Tags: naturalism, contemporary-philosophy, moral-realism

In current philosophy, what are the main strands of argumentation when it comes to substantiating naturlistic moral realism?

My question may be rephrased into: How would you argue?

Comment: "How would you argue" is off-topic here, but [SEP surveys](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-realism/#2) how philosophers proposed to reconcile moral facts with naturalism, particularly in connection with Moore's argument against their compatibility.